# Responsive image with max height

Tags: css, responsive-design

I would like, using CSS only, to have an image stretch to the max width of a container div, keeping aspect ratio, without using background images. However, if the height of the image exceeds X then it should be limited by that. The following doesn't cause the image to go 100%. If I set that then it becomes stretched if the height exceeds 200px.

```
.container {
   width: 200px;    
   position: relative;
}
img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
}

<div class="container"><img src=""></div>
```

Here's a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/cyberwombat/agfy1cfm/4/

Comment: I would use `height: auto;`

Comment: do you have anything else in the container apart from the image?

Comment: @sdcr no - however the reason I cannot use background image is that it's a gallery and I have thumbs that need to be positioned to the bottom of this larger image.

Comment: it seems not realistic from what you described above, the image has to be cut off a little if it's taller than 200px (originally or after stretch), see the demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/f7n8udks/ (it makes sure to keep the aspect ratio)

Comment: @sdcr perhaps. But SO is where dreams are made :)

Comment: Wait, so you want to image to exactly fit the container even if they have different aspect ratios and neither stretching not cropping (like @sdcr) suggested are options?

Comment: I want the entire image, not skewed, to fill the width of the container unless the image is to tall as to look weird in which case I want to limit it (without cropping). Basically I want 100% width but a max height set.

Comment: I should not that this is achievable with background image. The problem with that approach is that I need to place thumbnails just underneath and the background approach requires a set height. I may end up using this though and relocating my thumbs if I fail to achieve the above.

Comment: There is a way, but [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) isn't great at all. demo - http://jsfiddle.net/f7n8udks/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try just setting the height:

```
img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 50px
}
```

where the values of max-width and max-height match the dimensions of the container.

Comment: Causes outer div to blow up if image dosn't meet max height. Check out the fiddle where I set a huge max height - the image should not be more than 300px but in this case it blows up the div. http://jsfiddle.net/cyberwombat/agfy1cfm/1/

Comment: If the height is variable, set `width: 100%` and `max-width` instead?

Comment: Unfortunately a width of 100% when the container height is smaller than that of the image causes a stretch.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use instead this, **more flexible**:

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

With this, you can use whatever aspect-ratio image you want, being sure that the images will remain responsive